# Finding the highest value with the given constraints

Tags: python, arrays, list

```
c = [416,585,464]

A0 = [100,50,200]
A1 = [100,100,200]
A2 = [100,150,100]
A3 = [100,200,0]
A4 = [100,250,0]

b = [300,300,300,300,300]

for num in A0,A1,A2,A3,A4:
    t0 = num[0]*1 + num[1]*1 + num[2]*1
    t1 = num[0]*0 + num[1]*1 + num[2]*0
    t2 = num[0]*0 + num[1]*0 + num[2]*0
    t3 = num[0]*0 + num[1]*0 + num[2]*1
    t4 = num[0]*1 + num[1]*0 + num[2]*0
    t5 = num[0]*0 + num[1]*1 + num[2]*1
    t6 = num[0]*1 + num[1]*1 + num[2]*0
    t7 = num[0]*1 + num[1]*0 + num[2]*1
```

Now check each of the values in `t0` against each of its corresponding values in the `b` array. If any of the values from `t0` are greater than `300`, then `t0` is discarded.

If not, then multiply each `t_` value by the each corresponding `c` array value, and after that determine the highest value and print it.

For example: `t1` has `50,100,150,200,250`, all of which are equal to or below `300`, so we take `0*c[0] + 1*c[1] + 0*c[2]`, which gives us `585`. However, that isn't the highest value. The highest value is `1049`, which is acquired by `t5`. It has `250,300,250,200,250`. Taking `0*c[0] + 1*c[1] + 1*c[2]` gives `1049`

I am stuck here.

Comment: Is there any reason A3 and A4 are unused, or is it just because you don't want to have to make `32` t variables?

Comment: @TrevorMerrifield They are used. for num in...

Comment: @Master whoops my bad, I misread (thought the As were zipped together)

Comment: The description is not clear, but it sounds like you know what you need the code to do, so I'm not sure what your question is. Can you make it any simpler, or take a stab at writing some code to solve it so that answerers can identify what you're struggling with?

Comment: @trentcl I can simplify it. Give me about 15 mins.

Comment: `num[0]*1 + num[1]*1 + num[2]*1` is the same as `num[0] + num[1] + num[2]`, every single expression can be simplified to a simple addition.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, while im not sure OP's intention, I think he tries to highlight that the "coefficients" form binary numbers from 0 to 7. It's a guess. Not sure if it's true or not.

Comment: @trentcl     `if t0[0] or t0[1] or t[2] or t[3] or t[4] > 300: # t0,t1,.. should be in an array
        # Then t0 is discarded 
        # Test each t_
    else:
        # Multiply as in the description`                 I have no idea how to go any further with this

Comment: @PadraicCunningham where do i place this line? the actual answer is 1049.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That's the output for t1

Comment: wouldn't `zip(*(A0, A1, A2, A3, A4)) = zip(A0, A1, A2, A3, A4)`?

Comment: @TrevorMerrifield, yep,  it is.

Comment: @Tuan333, looks almost like it but the bits don't add up.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I got [working code](http://ideone.com/38FQTM) but it's a bit of a beast and I won't post it as answer because I don't want to explain it. But maybe it can still help clarify the problem? I'm curious whether you could do it with a cool numpy solution :-)

Comment: I have working code using itertools too but the max comes out at 1465 which is wrong according to the OP

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Well then yours isn't really "working" :-P

Comment: @StefanPochmann You don't have to explain it. I will understand it.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham To get 1465 you'd need to take all three values from `c`, but that's not allowed because if you add all three values from `A0`, then you get 350 which is higher than its allowed limit of 300 (A1, A2 and A4 also speak against using all three values).

Comment: Each iteration of `num` results in the eight `t_` values. So how would `t1` end up having `50,100,150,200,250` in it? The value in it won't be a list or tuple, just the single number equal to `num[0]*0 + num[1]*1 + num[2]*0` for that iteration.

Comment: @martineau They're the t1-values for A1 to A5. See the code I linked to, might make it clearer.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: There is no `A5`. If you understand the question, go ahead an post an answer.

Comment: @martineau Right, I meant A0 to A4. Like I said before, I won't post it as an answer because I don't want to explain it (and I wouldn't appreciate the downvotes of the spoonfeeder-nazis).

Comment: @Master It looks like some people have managed to divine your actual problem, but I'm still confused, so I've downvoted your post because it contains no actual question. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site and it's not well suited to generic problem statements like "I want to do such-and-such but I don't know how." See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); in particular, you should ask *specific* questions like "How do I put all these values in an array?" not merely "I'm stuck."

Answer (score 0):

I guess this does what you want—at least it produces sums  from the data similar to those you mentioned in your question. I found your sample code is *very* misleading since it doesn't produce the kind of `t_` values you refer to in the written problem description below it.

```
from itertools import compress

c = [416,585,464]

A0 = [100,50,200]
A1 = [100,100,200]
A2 = [100,150,100]
A3 = [100,200,0]
A4 = [100,250,0]

b = [300,300,300,300,300]

selectors = [(1, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1),
             (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1)]

nums_limits = zip((A0, A1, A2, A3, A4), b)
maximum = None
for selector in selectors:
    if all(sum(compress(nums, selector)) <= limit for nums,limit in nums_limits):
        total = sum(compress(c, selector))
        if maximum is None or total > maximum:
            maximum = total

print(maximum)  # -> 1049
```

You can replace most of that with one (longish) [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) similar to the one in [linked code](http://ideone.com/38FQTM) in one of  @Stefan Pochmann's comments, so this does exactly the same thing:

```
print(max(sum(compress(c, selector)) for selector in selectors
                  if all(sum(compress(nums, selector)) <= limit
                         for nums, limit in zip((A0, A1, A2, A3, A4), b))))
```